# How to show that two probability generating functions are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, power-series, generating-functions, expectation

From Grimmett's Probability and Random Processes:

> Let $G_a(s) := \sum_0^\infty a_is^i$ where $a = \{a_i : i \geq 0\}$ is 
>   a real sequence.
>
> Uniqueness. If $G_a(s) = G_b(s)$ for $|s| < R'$ where $0 < R' \leq R$ then $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$.

Is it enough to show that $G_a(s) = G_b(s)$ holds for all $s\in [0,R')$ instead of $s\in (-R',R')$?

Here is the context of my question. I want to understand the justification for the swap in:

$$G_{X_1+\cdots+X_N }(s)=\mathbb E\left(\sum_n \mathbf 1_{\{N=n\}} s^{X_1+\cdots+X_N }\right)= \sum_n \mathbb E\left( \mathbf 1_{\{N=n\}} s^{X_1+\cdots+X_N }\right)$$

As far as I can tell, the swap is unproblematic if $s \geq 0$.

Comment: Power series are unique and the coefficients have to be equal. One way to see this is that powers of x are linearly independent.

Comment: @grdgfgr: could you elaborate?